# Is there a way to reduce this bandwidth?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, backend, hosting, aws-amplify

I'm not sure how to formulate the question, so I'll give you a picture instead:

I've built a card browser React web app, and when user visits the page, it will lazily download 50mb of images. The app itself is 1mb.

The images are always the same, static number of them, no uploading or anything complex.

Now, if I host this on a server with average bandwidth price of $0.08/GB, and there are 10 000 daily visitors, it's 10000 x 30 x 50mb = 1500GB * $0.08 = $1200/month.

Is there a way to host those 50mb for the web app without paying $1200/mo for bandwidth?

Comment: So, just to be sure, your project has 50mb worth of images, is that it?

Comment: 50 MB. That's it. Fifty.

Comment: Not all users will download your images every time... after the first download they will remain on browser cache. Or are there 10.000 new visitors every day?

Comment: Maybe you can try to compress those images, which format are you using? what is average image height and width and what is the average size in Kb?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are using these images as project images (backgrounds, icons, etc).

The best approach I can think of right now is to upload those pictures to a S3 bucket (or even Google Drive to cheap in even further).

With those in hand, you can get the static generated links, and provide it in your app as remote images.